# installed Wordpress but can't upgrade or add plugins due to webdav https?

Tags: plugins, upgrade, https

Uploaded wordpress and themes via webdav https but can't seem to add plugins or upgrade Wordpress. I'm presuming the is a webdav security feature?

Is there any way around it?

Comment: have you checked files owner/permissions?

Comment: yeh they are rex (700?). Seems like the provider is being tight with permissions. I can't even change them via transmit and have no cpanel access. Hopefully this is the problem but will report back when i find out.